# Webpack-Dev-Server With Gulp Not Reloading After Code Change

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, webpack-dev-server

im new to webpack and im trying to get it to work with gulp. i am using the guide found at the following link, but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html
```

can anyone tell me which part of my configuration is wrong?

gulpfile.js

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import gutil from "gulp-util";
import WebpackDevServer from "webpack-dev-server";

import webpackConfig from './webpack.config';

gulp.task("dev-server", function(callback) {
    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {

    }).listen(4000, "localhost", function(err) {
        if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
        // Server listening
        gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", "http://localhost:4000/webpack-dev-server/index.html");

        // keep the server alive or continue?
        // callback();
    });
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    entry: {
        app: __dirname+'/dev/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['babel']},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `webpackConfig ` is what you are expecting. You might need to use `import * as webpackConfig from './webpack.config' `

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt affect anything. i can see things logged in the console and i can even see that the webpage refreshes, but the content remains the same.

Comment: Can you publish a screenshot of your network tab in chrome when you navigate to index.html?

Answer (score 0):

There are [differences between the Node.js API and the CLI for webpack dev server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/616). You are using the Node.js API so should see here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#via-the-node-js-api

Try something along these lines inside the gulp task defining function:

```
// Add entry points for '/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js' necessary for live reloading
WebpackDevServer.addDevServerEntrypoints(webpackConfig, { ... dev-server-options ...});

// Start a webpack-dev-server
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {

}).listen(4000, "localhost", function(err) {
    if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
    // Server listening
    gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", "http://localhost:4000/webpack-dev-server/index.html");

    // keep the server alive or continue?
    // callback();
});
```

Essentially add the one line `WebpackDevServer.addDevServerEntrypoints(webpackConfig, { ... dev-server-options ...});` to the beginning of your task function. This will add "/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js" as an entry to your webpack config and is needed for live reloading.